# Function to automatically create DrawText in RECT

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing the WinAPI Application, and I tried to write a function, that would automate for me creating Rectangles for text input (with Font, BkMode, TextColor), that then is called by DrawContent function called by WM_PAINT. The text does not appear, after I call `ELW::AddTextControl`.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ELW::WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            {
            ELW::DrawContent(hWnd, hInst, hdc);
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            UnregisterClass(CLASS_NAME, hInst);
            }
            break;

        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            {
            if (wParam == SC_CLOSE);
            break;
            }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

// Content drawing

void ELW::DrawContent(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInst, HDC hdc)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    RECT testowyRectangle = { 0, 1 , 20 , 30 };
    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_GRAYTEXT + 1));
    ELW::AddTextControl("Testowy test", 80, 80, 100, 100, CUSTOM_COLOR_YELLOW_COLORREF, 10, "Euroscope", hdc);


    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

};

void ELW::AddTextControl(const char* text, int xPos, int yPos, int xSize, int ySize, COLORREF rgb, int fontSize, const char* fontName, HDC hdc)
{
    RECT TextRectangle = { xPos, yPos, ( xPos + xSize ) , ( yPos + ySize ) }; // Left, Top, Right, Bottom
    
    if (rgb == NULL)
        rgb = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    if (fontSize == NULL)
        fontSize = 10;
    if (fontName == NULL)
        fontName = "Euroscope";


    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(fontSize, 8, 0, 0, 600, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT(fontName));
    SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(hdc, rgb);
    DrawText(hdc, TEXT(text), strlen(text), &TextRectangle, DT_CENTER | DT_NOCLIP);
}
```

Comment: In `DrawContent()`, what is the purpose of `testowyRectangle`? You are not using it for anything. Did you maybe meant to pass it to `AddTextControl()`?

Comment: It was just blank coloured Rectangle to test out behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

Found an error:
`strlen(text)`
should be
`strlen(TEXT(text))`

Comment: You can't use the `TEXT()` macro on variables, only on string/char literals at compile-time. The fact that `strlen(TEXT(text))` compiles at all means you are compiling without `UNICODE` defined, as `TEXT()` would do nothing in that case, replacing `TEXT(text)` with just `text`. But if `UNICODE` were defined, `TEXT(text)` would be replaced with `Ltext` and your code would fail to compile. `text` is a `const char*`, which is what `strlen()` takes without needing `TEXT()`.

Comment: Same goes with `TEXT(fontName)`, too. Since `text` and `fontName` are both `const char*`, you should be using `CreateFontA()` and `DrawTextA()` directly, not the generic `TCHAR`-based `CreateFont()` and `DrawText()`

Comment: Alright, I got you with the TEXT(). It compiles without it (but after changing to ```CreateFontA``` and ```DrawTextA``` functions) and it shows the ```text```.

Comment: Now, what I'd like to do is to update this DrawTextA with a function call (it's DLL, so let's say that caller is somewhere else, I can define functions to it, that it calls). I tried to create function ```ELW::UpdateContent()``` that would invoke ```UpdateWindow(hWnd)``` but I guess it's not enough. I read about ```InvalidateRect``` but not sure how should I use it.

Comment: I drawn the text with the AddTextControl, and assume I have a **timer**, that invokes specified methods/functions every second. ```text``` variable has been changed (by some other code). I want to specify a function to this **timer**, that would force Window to refresh/Update (so it will take new ```text```).

Comment: All you need to do is store the input values to `DrawTextA()` in some variables somewhere. Then you can update those variable values however you want as needed, then call `InvalidateRect()` on the window to trigger a repaint.  `WM_PAINT` can then pass the updated variables to `DrawTextA()`.